# Compilation error during calling methods containing Either and wildcards

Tags: java, wildcard

I have problem with understanding how Java wildcard works in one particular case. Let's say I have class which represents generic response

```
public class MyResponse<T> {

    private final int httpCode;
    private final String message;
    private final T data;
}
```

and resolver for that:

```
public class ResponseResolver {

    public void resolve(Either<AppError, MyResponse<?>> responseToResolve) {
        //some logic 
    }

    public void resolveOption(Option<MyResponse<?>> responseToResolve) {
        //some logic 
    }
}
```

and service where response is resolved with resolver

```
public class FooService {

    private final ResponseResolver responseResolver;

    public FooService(ResponseResolver responseResolver) {
        this.responseResolver = responseResolver;
    }

    public void resolveFoo() {
        Either<AppError, MyResponse<Foo>> either = Option.of(new MyResponse<>(200, "message", new Foo())).toEither(AppError.ERROR);
        responseResolver.resolve(either);
    }

    public void resolveOptionFoo() {
        MyResponse<Foo> foo = new MyResponse<>(200, "message", new Foo());
        responseResolver.resolveOption(Option.of(foo));
    }
}
```

I do not understand why `resolveOption` method which is called in `resolveFooOption` is a proper way but in method with `Either` compiler complies that required type is `Either<AppError, MyResponse<?>` but provided `Either<AppError, MyResponse<Foo>`. Can anybody explain me why second case is invalid?

Comment: Did you try `Either<AppError, MyResponse<?>> either = ...`, so the type of `either` matches the parameter type of method `resolve()`?

Comment: Yes I tried it and it works. But I am still curious about why the first version does not work. I thought that adding wildciard allows to pass any value. Especially that method with `Option<?>` works.

Comment: Because `Either<AppError, MyResponse<Foo>>` and `Either<AppError, MyResponse<?>>` are not assignment-compatible, see [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5221149)

Comment: The `Option<?>` variant works for the same reason that `Either<AppError, MyResponse<?>>` works, i.e. that `Option.of()` resolves to that type specifically, not to a type naming `Foo`.